# Как реализовать смену шаблона Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Есть два шаблона. Как реализовать смену шаблона по ссылке для переключения на новый дизайн и старый дизайн. Например c помощью переключения по ссылке с GET параметром ?template=new_design.

Comment: возможно, template, а не tamplate?

Comment: Я думал тут могут помочь с решением задачи, а тут орфографию проверяют

Answer (score 1):

Настройки - Настройки продукта - Сайты - Список сайтов, выбираете нужный сайт (там скорее всего один).

Для нужного шаблона выбираете тип условия "Параметр в URL" и заполняете.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Я так понимаю этот параметр будет доступен в сессии. Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос. Это обычный GET-параметр в урле. При переходе со страницы на страницу он не будет сохранятся. Если нужен такой функционал - тогда надо написать небольшой код, который будет сохранять параметр в сессии. После этого нужно поменять Тип условия на "Выражение PHP" и туда вставить код, который будет чекать параметр в сессии.

Comment: Планировалась ссылка с гет параметром, чтобы переключать главную на старый/новый макет.